# Table Partitioning advice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to take advantage of partitioning on a massive table, both for query improvement as well as archiving.

There are multiple tables using the same formatting but just as an example:

```
Create Table Example(
id int,
transactiondate date,
transactiontimestamp datetime2(7)
--Lots of other columns here)
```

On insert into these tables, transactiondate is extracted from transactiontimestamp.

```
Vb.Net example
StoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@TransactionDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
StoredProcedure.Parameters("@TransactionDate").Value = New DateTime(Transaction.TransactionDate.Year, Transaction.TransactionDate.Month, Transaction.TransactionDate.Day)
StoredProcedure.Parameters.Add("@TransactionTimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime2)
StoredProcedure.Parameters("@TransactionTimeStamp").Value = Transaction.TransactionDate
```

I'm not able to alter the insert transactions as the above code is boiler plated all over the place in different interfaces.

My issue is that a significant number of querys are done on both the TransactionTimeStamp (for OLTP purposes) and TransactionDate for reporting purposes.

Partitioning on TransactionDate makes sense as we'll be archiving based on it, as well as helping reporting out. However it does nothing for the processing transactions which rarely join on to TransactionDate...

Any advice welcome on how I could better utilise these tables.
"I'm trying to get into a position where I can easily archive large chunks of data, which I was hoping to do via date partitioning. I'm also hoping to obtain the benefit of partition exclusion for queries hitting these tables."

Comment: Consider merging the two columns. What's the point of storing the same data twice? Eg you can use filter on `transactiontimestamp` to get whole days (using half-open intervals). When you say massive, how massive? Unless you are running into the tens of millions of rows and are bulk inserting or bulk-deleting, it's probably pointless to partition anyway.

Comment: Yes tens of millions or more. Merging the two columns would be ideal however that would require significant changes to procedures/interfaces, some of which I might not be able to access.

Comment: *"Any advice welcome"* you need to be a bit more specific here on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to get into a position where I can easily archive large chunks of data, which I was hoping to do via date partitioning. I'm also hoping to obtain the benefit of partition exclusion for queries hitting these tables.

Comment: Can't have your cake and eat it too. Partitioning by creation date makes sense, but then having queries exclude it without it being in the query is not an option. A potential workaround is to retarget your queries to a view that has a broad exclusion on the range so it leaves partitions that are about to archived alone. (Still doable if your application code is immutable by making the view updatable and swapping names, though that isn't entirely trivial.) You can also start considering things like replication and reshaping data to serve different purposes.